# Must a recursion be represented only in terms of definition of a recursive function?

Tags: programming-languages

In programming languages, must a recursion be represented only in terms of definition of a recursive function?

Does a recursion appear in other cases?

I ask this question, because recursion and loop are two equivalent ways to make a programming language Turing complete. Loop doesn't depend on function, and does recursion also not?

Thanks.

Comment: There are recursive definitions of things that are not strictly functions (types, for instance). Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Perhaps not. Recursion in types doesn't contribute to Turing completeness. What I mean by recursion is recursion that contributes to Turing completeness, i.e. recursion in control flow.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at [the definition of recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion):

> Recursion occurs when a thing is defined in terms of itself or of its type.

This means you need some sort of object (not in the OOP sense), which can be defined in terms of other objects of the same kind.

A function is usually defined as a list of statements in imperative languages or as an expression in functional languages. Statements and expressions can contain function calls, which means a function can be recursive:

```c++
void f()
{
    f();
}
```

```f#
let f () = f ()
```

But there are other objects that can (at least potentially) be recursive.

Structures are types that contain fields, of other types:

```c++
struct S
{
    S* s;
};
```

Classes inherit from other classes, but a class inheriting from itself doesn't make much sense, so it's not allowed in the languages I know:

```c++
class C : C
{
};
```

(There is a related concept of [the curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but that's not really recursion.)

It could also make sense to define a value in terms of itself (for example, when creating a single-value cyclic linked list):

```c#
var item = new Item { Next = item };
```

Though most languages won't allow this and require you to construct such value in two steps:

```c#
var item = new Item();
item.Next = item;
```

---

But, for something to be Turing-complete, it has to define a *computation*. These other examples don't do that. Though if you look at more exotic languages, you can find that too.

For example, predicate in Prolog can be defined using other predicates:

```prolog
p :- p.
```

Predicates are in some aspects similar to functions, but they're not really the same.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion appears in programming languages in many forms. The purest form is a [fixed-point operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) $\mathtt{fix}$ which takes a function $f$ and computes its fixed point:
$$\mathtt{fix}(f) = f(\mathtt{fix}(f))$$
In a lazy functional programming language you can define $\mathtt{fix}$ exactly as above, e.g., in Haskell:

```
Prelude> let fix f = f (fix f)
Prelude> :t fix
fix :: (t -> t) -> t
```

Then `fix` can be used for many purposes. Let us look at some examples. First, if we have a recursively defined function
$$g(x) = \Phi(g, x)$$
where $\Phi$ is the body of $g$, we can get $g$ defined non-recursively as
$$g = \mathtt{fix}(\lambda h \, x \,.\, \Phi(h, x))$$
For instance, in Haskell we can use fix to define the factorial function:

```
Prelude> let fact = fix (\ h x -> if x == 0 then 1 else x * h (x - 1))
Prelude> fact 10
3628800
```

But we can also define other recursive structures. For instance, suppose we want a list $\ell$ such that
$$\ell = 1 : 2 : 3 : \ell$$
Then $\ell = \mathtt{fix}(\lambda x \,.\, 1 : 2 : 3 : x)$. Indeed:

```
Prelude> fix (\ x -> 1 : 2 : 3 : x)
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1 ....
```

Of course, we do not have to use `fix`, that's just an interesting theoretical gadget. Haskell allows recursive definitions of non-functions:

```
Prelude> let myList = 1 : 2 : 3 : myList
Prelude> myList
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2, ...
```

A less silly example is the list of prime numbers, defined recursively as:

- the first element is $2$
- the rest of the list consists of those numbers $n \geq 3$ which are not divisible by any number $k$ in the list of primes such that $k^2 \leq n$

Let us try:

```
let primes = 2 : [ n | n <- [3..50], all (\k -> n `mod` k /= 0) (takeWhile (\x -> x * x <= n) primes)]
Prelude> primes
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,257,263,269,271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,467,479,487,491,499,503,509,521,523,541,547,557,563,569,571,577,587,593,599,601,607,613,617,619,631,641,643,647,653,659,661,673,677,683,691,701,709,719,727,733,739,743,751,757,761,769,773,787,797,809,811,821,823,827,829,839,853,857,859,863,877,881,883,887,907,911,919,929,937,941,947,953,967,971,977,983,991,997,1009,1013,1019,1021,1031,1033,1039,1049,1051,1061,1063,1069,1087,1091,1093,1097,1103,1109,1117,1123,1129,11
```

Does this mean we can also define a number $n$ such that $n = n + 1$? Absolutely:

```
Prelude> let n = n + 1
Prelude> n
```

Haskell goes into an infinite loop, of course. The "number" so defined is the "undefined number".

There is also recursion at the level of types. It happens whenever we have a definition of a type which refers to the type itself. Examples are lists, trees, classes in objective-oriented programming, etc. Here too we have a fixed-point operator, except that this times it works at the level of types: given a *type constructor $F$* (a function from types to types), $\mathtt{Fix}(F)$ is a type $T$ such that $T \cong F(T)$. For example, if
$$T(X) = \mathtt{unit} + \mathtt{int} \times X$$
then $\mathtt{Fix}(T)$ is the type of lists of integers. (I am skipping details on *which* fixed point is computed by $\mathtt{fix}$ and $\mathtt{Fix}$.)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to name examples of recursion used to define computations in Turing-complete models that are not based on functions. Unrestricted grammars is one of them.

What you end up creating can always be *interpreted* as a function, nonetheless.

Comment: So computations in grammars are described in languages not based on functions. So the languages are not in functional paradigm, but in what paradigm? If I am correct, grammars are rewriting systems, and do the languages describing grammars belong to logical paradigm?

Comment: If you want an example of computational model that is not strictly functional, uses recursion, and has inspired a programming language paradigm, then logic programming is one.

Comment: Do the languages which describe grammars belong to some paradigm?

Comment: To my knowledge, there aren't programming languages directly based on unrestricted grammars, and it definitely hasn't produced a programming paradigm. A computational model is not a programming language.